# tkinter combobox, Entry correctly show when run from same file. But does not show correct values when same is called from another module

Tags: python, tkinter

when I call same function from within the file it shows correct values. The values are filled in same module. But when I call it`enter code here` from another module it does not show values in widgets. I have gone thru similar problems solved earlier but they are solved from within the module.( I am new to python but have worked for many years on visual basic I am in the process of porting my code to python.)

In similar problems somebody suggested app.wait_window. This helped in showing the values if called from same file. As suggested in other solution I am using Class.

demobill.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import datetime

class Bill(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("BILL")
        self.grid()
        topfrm = tk.Frame(self)
        topfrm.config(bg="yellow", height=350, width=500)
        topfrm.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)
        lbl1 = tk.Label(topfrm, text="Party   :", bg="light green")
        lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.vparty = tk.StringVar()
        self.mParty=ttk.Combobox(topfrm,textvariable=self.vparty,width=20, values =('apple', 'banana', 'CranBerry', 'dogwood', 'alpha', 'Acorn', 'Anise' ))
        self.mParty.state = 'readonly'
        self.mParty.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.mregdt=tk.StringVar()
        self.regdt = tk.Entry(topfrm, width=12, background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
        self.regdt['textvariable']=self.mregdt
        self.regdt.grid(row=2, column=1)
        lblbillno = tk.Label(topfrm, text="Bill No:")
        lblbillno.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=10)
        self.mbillno = tk.StringVar()
        billno = tk.Entry(topfrm, textvariable= self.mbillno, width=16, justify=tk.LEFT)
        billno.grid(row=3,column=1)
        self.mdr = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.mcr = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.edr = tk.Entry(topfrm, textvariable= self.mdr, width=16, justify=tk.RIGHT)
        self.edr.grid(row=4,column=1)
        self.ecr = tk.Entry(topfrm, textvariable= self.mcr, width=16, justify=tk.RIGHT)
        self.ecr.grid(row=5,column=1)
        btnQuit = tk.Button(topfrm, text='Quit', padx=5, width=10, command=self.cmdQuit)
        btnQuit.grid(row=10, column=3)

def cmdQuit(self):
    self.destroy()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        exit()
    else:
        self.master.destroy()

def bill_readfill(self,bill_id):
    mregdt="2019-01-01"
    self.mregdt.set(mregdt)
    self.mbillno.set( 101)
    self.vparty.set('banana')
    self.mdr.set(1000)
    # print (self.mdr.get())
    self.mcr.set(100)

def billtest(bill_id):
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()))
    app = Bill(root)
    app.bill_readfill(bill_id)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    billtest(1)
```

democall.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import demobill


def runbill():
    demobill.billtest(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    btncolr = "#2255ff"
    btnNew = tk.Button(root, text='bill', padx=5, bd=2,width=10, bg=btncolr, command=runbill)               
    btnNew.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

no error messages. The values are there. They can be printed from within. Just not shown in widget.

Comment: You have two separate instances of `Tk` in these two files, and they cannot communicate between each other. If you needed additional window, use `Toplevel()`.

Comment: Thanks Henry, I made following change and it worked.                                       def billtest(bill_id):
    root=tk.Tk() ----> root=tk.Toplevel()   However it shows extra window when run from demobill.py.  Thanks again.

Comment: @PrashantBastodkar If you want only one of the windows to be visible at once, pass `root` as an additional argument to`runbill` and add the following line to `runbill()`: `root.withdraw()`.